# ESET nod32 antivirus creating huge files in temp folder

Tags: anti-virus, nod32

I'm running ESET nod32 antivirus on Windows 7 64 bit machine. I can see huge files being created and being locked by the ESET nod32 antivirus .Why is this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

These are temp files created by Eset when an application is downloading something, Eset uses these to scan the files before actually writing them where they belong.

http://www.wilderssecurity.com/showthread.php?t=239810

.

Comment: i tried deleting them, but are recreated again..how do i stop that because I'm losing about 7 gb of disk space

Comment: I would contact Eset support. http://www.eset.com/support/contact  ..or the Eset forums..http://www.wilderssecurity.com/forumdisplay.php?s=3d8f047a4f85c77d3e9716791f4f3537&f=88